# Calculating mean grade of students' peers

Tags: r, networking, network-programming, stata

I have one dataset which includes all the points of students and other variables.

I further have a diagonal matrix which includes information on which student is a peer of another student.

Now I would like to use the second matrix (network) to calculate the mean-peer-points for each student. Everyone can have different (number of) peers.
To calculate the mean, I recalculated the simple 0,1 matrix into percentages, whereby the denominator is the sum of the number of peers one student has.

The second matrix then would look something like this:

```
     ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4  ID5
ID1  0    0    0    0    1
ID2  0    0    0.5  0.5  0
ID3  0    0.5  0    0    0.5
ID4  0    0.5  0    0    0.5 
ID5  0.33 0    0.33 0.33 0
```

And the points of each students is a simple variable in another dataset, and I would like to have the peers-average-points in as a second variable:

```
ID  Points Peers
ID1 45     11
ID2 42     33.5
ID3 25     26.5
ID4 60     26.5
ID5 11     43.33
```

Are there any commands in Stata for that problem? I am currently looking into the Stata commands `nwcommands`, but I am unsure whether it can help. I could use solutions for Stata and R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nwcommands` is an outstanding package I have never used or studied, so I will just try the problem from first principles. This is all matrix algebra, but given a matrix and a variable, I would approach it like this in Stata.

```
clear 

scalar third = 1/3 
mat M = (0,0,0,0,1\0,0,0.5,0.5,0\0,0.5,0,0,0.5\0,0.5,0,0,0.5\third,0,third,third,0)

input ID Points Peers
 1 45 11
 2 42 33.5
 3 25 26.5
 4 60 26.5
 5 11 43.33
end 

gen Wanted = 0 

quietly forval i = 1/5 { 
   forval j = 1/5 { 
       replace Wanted = Wanted + M[`i', `j'] * Points[`j']  in `i' 
   }
} 

list 

      +--------------------------------+
     | ID   Points   Peers     Wanted |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |  1       45      11         11 |
  2. |  2       42    33.5       42.5 |
  3. |  3       25    26.5       26.5 |
  4. |  4       60    26.5       26.5 |
  5. |  5       11   43.33   43.33334 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Small points: Using 0.33 for 1/3 doesn't give enough precision. You'll have similar problems for 1/6 and 1/7, for example.

Also, I get that the peers of 2 are 3 and 4 so their average is (25 + 60)/2 = 42.5, not 33.5.

EDIT: A similar approach starts with a data structure very like that imagined by @ander2ed

```
clear
input int(id points  id1 id2 id3 id4 id5)
1 45  0 0 0 0 1
2 42  0 0 1 1 0 
3 25  0 1 0 0 1 
4 60  0 1 0 0 1 
5 11  1 0 1 1 0  
end

gen wanted = 0 

quietly forval i = 1/5 { 
   forval j = 1/5 { 
       replace wanted = wanted + id`j'[`i'] * points[`j'] in `i' 
   }
} 

egen count = rowtotal(id1-id5)  
replace wanted = wanted/count 

list 



    +--------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   points   id1   id2   id3   id4   id5     wanted   count |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       45     0     0     0     0     1         11       1 |
  2. |  2       42     0     0     1     1     0       42.5       2 |
  3. |  3       25     0     1     0     0     1       26.5       2 |
  4. |  4       60     0     1     0     0     1       26.5       2 |
  5. |  5       11     1     0     1     1     0   43.33333       3 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Assuming OP will always be working with an NxN student-peer matrix, the general solution is of course to iterate the `forvalues` loops from `1 to _N`. I'm not sure this assumption is warranted but in the context of the question it seems to be.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it should always be a NxN matrix (in my case). And with the precision, sure, take the point.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting too creative, you can accomplish what you are trying to do with `reshape`, `collapse` and a couple of `merge`s in Stata. Generally speaking, data in long format is easier to work with for this type of exercise.

Below is an example which produces the desired result.

```
/* Set-up data for example */
clear
input int(id points)
1 45
2 42
3 25
4 60
5 11
end
tempfile points
save `points'

clear
input int(StudentId id1 id2 id3 id4 id5)
1 0 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 1 1 0
3 0 1 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 0 1
5 1 0 1 1 0
end
/* End data set-up */

* Reshape peers data to long form
reshape long id, i(Student) j(PeerId)
drop if id == 0 // drop if student is not a peer of `StudentId`

* create id variable to use in merge
replace id = PeerId

* Merge to points data to get peer points
merge m:1 id using `points', nogen

* collapse data to the student level, sum peer points
collapse (sum) PeerPoints = points (count) CountPeers = PeerId, by(StudentId)

* merge back to points data to get student points
rename StudentId id
merge 1:1 id using `points', nogen

gen peers = PeerPoints / CountPeers
li id points peers

     +------------------------+
     | id   points      peers |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  1       45         11 |
  2. |  2       42       42.5 |
  3. |  3       25       26.5 |
  4. |  4       60       26.5 |
  5. |  5       11   43.33333 
     +------------------------+
```

In the above code, I `reshape` your peer data into long form data and keep only student-peer pairs. I then merge this data to the points data to get the points of each students peers. From here, I `collapse` the data back to the student level, totaling peer points and peer count in the process. At this point, you have total points for the peers of each student and the number of peers each student has. Now, you simply have to `merge` back to the points data to get the subject students points and divide total peer points (`PeerPoints`) by the number of peers the student has (`CountPeers`) for average peer points.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it!

Comment: Indeed there is, however I have no familiarity with `nwcommands` myself. The matrix approach is nice because it is concise, but when thinking about a solution, my initial thought was that `reshape`/`merge` was easier to understand, hence the suggestion. On second thought, I'm not so sure. In any case, good answer.

Comment: Your data set-up is the one I would personally prefer!

Comment: I've exploited your data example to show another way to do it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It does give me the solution, but the second answers seems a bit faster, which is why I have decided to mark this one. But thank you very much for your answer!